JavaScriptの正規表現のパターンをスラッシュで囲む時、複数行に分けて書くことはできますか？
<script>
  let tag = '<div id="id1">text11</div>.*?<div id="id2">text12<\/div>\n<div id="id1">text21</div>.*?<div id="id2">text22<\/div>';
  let regExp = /<div id="id1">(.*?)<\/div>.*?<div id="id2">(.*?)<\/div>/g;

  while ((ret = regExp.exec(tag)) !== null) {
    console.log(ret[1] + ' '  + ret[2] + '\n');
  }
</script>

このコードを実行すると、コンソールに
text11 text12
text21 text22

と表示されます。
正規表現のパターン(regExp)を複数行にすることはできますか？
たとえば
let regExp = /<div id="id1">(.*?)<\/div>.*?/g
+ /<div id="id2">(.*?)<\/div>/g;

のように書くとエラーになります。
正規表現のパターンが長い場合見にくくなるので、できれば複数行に分けて記載したいのです。

let regExp = /<div id="id1">(.*?)<\/div>.*?<div id="id2">(.*?)<\/div>/g;

はRexExpクラスを使うと
let regExp = new RegExp('<div id="id1">(.*?)<\/div>.*?<div id="id2">(.*?)<\/div>', 'g');

と書くことができます。この場合は文字列引数になりますので、自由に組み立て可能です。

ありがとうございます！この記法は使ったことなかったので気づきませんでした。大変助かりました。これでだいぶみやすくできそうです。
